# How to interpret residual covariances in lavaan

Tags: residuals, lavaan

I generating a PA model using `lavaan`, so I would like to evaluate my model using fit indexes but residuals too.

Reading about I found this example:

```
library(lavaan)

# The Holzinger and Swineford (1939) example
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

fit <- lavaan(HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939,
              auto.var=TRUE, auto.fix.first=TRUE,
              auto.cov.lv.x=TRUE)
summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)


# View Residuals (documentation in the lavaan-class help file)
resid(fit, type='normalized')

and the result was:
$type
[1] "normalized"

$cov
   x1     x2     x3     x4     x5     x6     x7     x8     x9    
x1  0.000                                                        
x2 -0.493  0.000                                                 
x3 -0.125  1.539  0.000                                          
x4  1.159 -0.214 -1.170  0.000                                   
x5 -0.153 -0.459 -2.606  0.070  0.000                            
x6  0.983  0.507 -0.436 -0.130  0.048  0.000                     
x7 -2.423 -3.273 -1.450  0.625 -0.617 -0.240  0.000              
x8 -0.655 -0.896 -0.200 -1.162 -0.624 -0.375  1.170  0.000       
x9  2.405  1.249  2.420  0.808  1.126  0.958 -0.625 -0.504  0.000

$mean
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

How would I interpret these? Would somebody send me a reference? I am looking for an interpretation of this in `lavaan` and could not find good material.

Answer (score 3):

`lavaan` is a structural equation modeling (SEM) package in `R`, and, as with all SEM programs, the analysis works primarily on the observed covariance matrix (i.e., the covariance matrix generated from the raw variables included in the model). The general goal of any SEM model is to identify a set of maximally likely population parameters given a) the variances and covariances of the observed data and b) several user-specified paths thought to give rise to said variances and covariances.

The residuals returned by the code you used represent the difference between the observed covariance matrix and the model-implied covariance matrix. By themselves these values are not particularly interesting though they are used as the basis for a number of model fit indices often used to guide model development and hypothesis testing within an SEM framework.

Comment: for your answer.

Sorry but I do not understand well, 
1. You mean in SEM the residuals are used to work with other indices and it is not interesting to use themselves?
2. I am new in SEM, I have seem another examples where scatter plot are generated and examined to see the residual behavior. There is not similar in SEM?

Comment: So the residuals are not the same as residuals you calculate in say a regression. In OLS regression the residuals represent the deviation of the observed scores on your dependent variable $y$ from your predicted values ($\hat{y}$) based on the regression model. In SEM (and specifically in `lavaan` using the code you did), the residuals represent the deviation of the observed covariance matrix of your variables from their model-implied covariance matrix.

Comment: Understand @Matt Barstead, thank you, so based on this results I can say my model above had not a good fit since the values in covariance matrix of residuals are high. Except for x5 to x4 that is 0.070. 

In another case if all values area low like 0.004 for example with also good SRMR, RMR, CFI, TLI RMSEA I can say my model had a good fit over data?

I am just looking for a literature explaining this in lavaan.

Comment: It is better to use the fit indices you listed above to assess model fit. Diagnostically it can also be useful to examine the correlation matrix residuals. The covariance matrix residuals are generally difficult to interpret as their magnitude is tied to the units of measure.

Answer (score 3):

Kline (2016) suggests using the *lavaan* residuals (type = "cor") to identify residuals > |.10|. Such residuals indicate a likely specification error and could inform a decision to respecify a model.  See chapter 11 in

Kline, R. B. (2016). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling (4th ed.). Guilford Press.